# Amazon s3, Paperclip, Heroku - trying to make it work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm having trouble using Amazon s3 to manage Paperclip uploaded images via Heroku. I'm new at this, and need help.

My Gemfile is configured thus:

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.0'

gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2'
```

I've googled the problem and I'm sure the bucket and required keys are configured as they should be. Below is the error message.

```
2015-10-10T15:42:22.470342+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.4ms)  BEGIN
2015-10-10T15:42:22.538108+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "pins" ("description", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["description", "huggable dog"], ["image_file_name", "huskie.jpg"], ["image_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["image_file_size", 107437], ["image_updated_at", "2015-10-10 15:42:21.625762"], ["user_id", 3], ["created_at", "2015-10-10 15:42:22.532123"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-10 15:42:22.532123"]]
2015-10-10T15:42:23.614978+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/pins" host=pixblog.herokuapp.com request_id=a95e7cb8-bfd6-4de9-9e76-51f697f1b5d0 fwd="50.185.53.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2468ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-10-10T15:42:23.607308+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
2015-10-10T15:42:23.610744+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-10T15:42:23.610748+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):
2015-10-10T15:42:23.610749+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:31:in `create'
2015-10-10T15:42:23.610751+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-10T15:42:23.610752+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-10T15:42:23.608813+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2004ms (ActiveRecord: 5.8ms)
updating Heroku CLI...Update hash signature mismatch
/Users/DigitalEtchings/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:10:in `error'
/Users/DigitalEtchings/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in update'
/usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
/Users/DigitalEtchings/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:116:in `block in update'
/Users/DigitalEtchings/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:88:in `wait_for_lock'
/Users/DigitalEtchings/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:112:in `update'
/Users/DigitalEtchings/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:101:in `autoupdate'
/Users/DigitalEtchings/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
/usr/local/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'
```

I understand the argument error which points to `pins_controller.rb`, the code on that page handles the result of image upload - which is not happening. Help?

Answer (score 0):

I've provided an explanation for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028047/rails-argumenterror-missing-required-bucket-option-fixes-not-working/32642942#32642942)

It should get you setup with paperclip, S3 & Heroku.

Comment: Great. I don't have errors anymore. Everything is almost right. Almost. The images do not show up! (They just have a Question mark where they should be.) I checked the Amazon console and the images are sitting in there. What could possibly be the problem now?? I'll sleep on this for now, but I feel I've gone over the hump. Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help.

Comment: If the bucket has the images, that means the mechanism within your app works. Could be a number of reasons why they're not being shown. I'd start with checking my bucket permissions. Next, how i'm showing them in the view.

Answer (score 0):

> ArgumentError (**missing required :bucket option**):

The error just means you don't have the options set up for your `Paperclip` instance in your app.

There is a [great tutorial here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3).

You'll need to do the following:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}
```

This is then combined with `Heroku`'s `ENV` variable assignment as follows:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
```

In Rails 4+, you'll be best placed to use their [`config/secrets.rb` hash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml):

```
#config/secrets.rb
production:
   s3:
     :bucket: "bucket_name"
     :access: "access_key_id"
     :secret: "secret_access_key"
```

This will give you the ability to reference:

```
#config/application.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id:      Rails.application.secrets.s3[:access],
    secret_access_key:  Rails.application.secrets.s3[:sercret]
  }
  bucket: Rails.application.secrets.s3[:bucket]
}
```

The beauty of this is that you can then populate your `secrets` with `ENV` vars:

```
#config/secrets.rb
development: 
   s3:
     :bucket: "dev_bucket_name"
     :access: "access_key_id"
     :secret: "secret_access_key"
production:
   s3:
     :bucket: ENV["AMAZON_S3_BUCKET"]
     :access: ENV["AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
     :secret: ENV["AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
```

We've found a small issue with the standard `Heroku` recommendation; you need to include the `bucket` option for `paperclip` outside of the `s3_credentials` hash:

[image]

---

In respect to the images not appearing, there are a number of potential issues:

**Upload**

Are your images actually being uploaded?

The simplest way to check is to go to your S3 account and look for them. If they're there, it suggests you have a permissions / Rails issue preventing them from showing; if not, it means you'll have some sort of other issue.

From what you've posted, I would strongly recommend picking through your Heroku logs. If you don't like looking through reams of text, you may wish to add [LogEntries](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries) to your app -- it allows you to view the *live* feed, which gives you explicit logs from Rails.

**Rails**

One of the more common issues with Rails is that it will still be trying to load the assets from your local destination. We always use `s3_host_name` to specify the host Paperclip will be pulling the data from.

This is a problem particularly with European buckets - we got around it by defining `s3_host_name`, as you can see above.